# How can I export data from a google spreadsheet to create an arrayToDataTable that I can use in a chart?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I've test this code using numbers instead off the elements "`ergo[ ].getvalue()`"  and it works, but I need to create an object or something to use only the range from my cells to don't need to change the numbers in the code and edit it only in the spreadsheet.

Here's what I tried:

```
 var ergonodata = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ow_rhF3sibKL3OAQRXpK6LLZDjMOhW-5DKyWWiN5iZg/edit#gid=638513192?range=B3:B6');  
 var dataErgonomia = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Trimestre','Percentual','Bronze','Prata','Ouro'],
        ['Q1',ergonodata[0].getValue(),60,90,95],
        ['Q2',ergonodata[1].getValue(),60,90,95],
        ['Q3',ergonodata[2].getValue(),60,90,95],
        ['Q4',ergonodata[3].getValue(),60,90,95],
       ]);
 var optionsErgonomia = {'title':'M1 - Ergonomia'
    vAxis: {title: '%'},
    hAxis: {title: 'Trimestre'},
    seriesType:'bars',
    series:{1:{type:'line'},
            2:{type:'line'}, 
            3:{type:'line'}
            }
  };
var ergonomiachart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('ergoChart'));
  ergonomiachart.draw(dataErgonomia,optionsErgonomia);
```

I've tried also using the function `getValues()` after open the spreadsheet with the Url

Comment: Are you having any issues? If so, you need to state them, in detail. Error messages, line numbers, research efforts, etc. Posting working code that has no attempt at doing what you are trying to do is like posting no code at all IMO.

Comment: in this case is not showing any error to me, it just don't show any charts in my page